# Google Signin with IE11 & Edge not working

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, google-signin

I'm trying to add Google Signin to our login page.  I've followed the code supplied by Google, as well as a GitHub project that I used for code example.  Both work perfect on Chrome, FireFox, Safari, but I can't get it to work on IE11 or Edge.

The GitHub project is at https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript.  This project uses Google's newer apis.google.com, however I've also tried plus.google.com as suggested in another post.  Neither work.

I added a data-onfailure function to the button, and get an error "popup_blocked_by_browser" even though the popup blocker is turned off in the browser.  Even though I get this popup error, I do get a popup that asks which Google account to use, but when I choose one, I get the "The webpage your are viewing is trying to close the window" message.  If I choose Yes, the window closes, but I don't get logged in.

Anyone have any advice for getting this to work in IE or Edge?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem on IE 11 with Windows 10.

I fixed it and then it happened again after receiving Windows Updates - annoying!

Here is what fixed it for me; it was an IE Setting.

Go to: 
IE -> Internet Options -> Security

Check "Apply" and then "OK" To exit.
[IE Settings Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3SaR.png)

Finally, restart IE.